# Remembering which monitor an application lives on

Tags: mac, multiple-monitors

Is there an app or something that will remember which monitor an application should "live" on?

I am hooking my mac laptop up to 2 monitors and there are 3 screens. Every time I unplug then replug the monitors to the laptop, the applications are all jumbled up and I have to go through and move the applications to the setup that I like. It'd be ideal if the applications knew which monitor it resided on so plugging/unplugging is a seamless experience.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using an application called [Stay](https://cordlessdog.com/stay/). Been using it for a few days and it seems to be pretty good.